# 2 fathers and sons: but 3 fish

Tags: riddle

Two fathers and their two sons go fishing together. Each of them catches one fish to take home with them. They do not lose/eat/smoke any fish, and yet when they arrive at home they only have three fish. How can this be?

Comment: Please make sure, while asking your question, there is no question yet that is similar (duplicate). SE provides you with a lot of suggestions when you're working on your question of other questions with similar titles / contents.

Comment: @Radhato i went through ALL of the suggestions and I didn't see the coffins one. I don't know how to otherwise find a dupe that is so differently worded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3 Generations: Grandpa, Father, and Son. Grandpa and Father are each a father; Father and Son are each a son.

Answer (score 1):

> Father,  son,  and grandson.
> Father
> Son (also a father )
> Grandson  (second son)
> 3 people, 3 fish.

Comment: Thanks and welcome to puzzling! Slightly better explained than the other answer, but already correctly answered.

Comment: @Adamawesome4 thanks! I noticed that after i had already posted :-/